# querying solr for count: omit fields when rows = 0?

Tags: solr, querying

I am optimizing queries for fetching from a solr backend and was asking myself:

If i query only for a facet for counting expected results, i query for 0 rows to be returned, because i just need the amount.
Does it additionally help (regarding execution performance) to explicitly query for an empty field list? Or is this not relevant for solr internal execution when already returning 0 rows?
What does the `maxScore` stand for?

// query #1: no explicit field list
`/select?q=*:*&rows=0&wt=json`

// query #2: explicit empty field list
`/select?q=*:*&rows=0&fl=[]&wt=json`

actual results for #1:

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 1000,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 1,
    "docs": []
}
```

actual results for #2:

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 1000,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
}
```

Thank you very much for your answers and explanations.